# Polymer core-animated-pages default page

Tags: javascript, polymer

I'm using the [Polymer](http://www.polymer-project.org) [`core-animated-pages`](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-animated-pages) to switch between my websites main pages.

I select which page needs to be shown by the id of that `<section>`. You can see a sample in action [here](http://jsbin.com/xequvone/1/edit). Now, the issue I'm having is that at loading of the page, the page that should be selected gets loaded from the url, eg `www.example.com/home` shows the home page, `www.example.com/activities` shows the activities page (code left out of example since not really relevant).

But what should I do when the id provided in the link doesn't exist? Is there an option to show a default `core-animated-pages`-page with a 404 message? Or do I have to check every link if it's in an array of all my pages, if so load the error page manually and else show the correct page?

Again, here's the example: [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/xequvone/1/edit).

**Edit:** To show the way my page handles linking, here's an update example: [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/xequvone/8/edit). Linking is essentially `www.example.com/#home`, etcetera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things you could do here.

In the simplest case, you could just validate the value in the pageChanged handler.  If the page doesn't exist, update it:

`pageChanged: function(){
  var foundPage = this.$.pages.querySelector('#' + this.page);
  if (! foundPage) {
    this.page = 'error'
  }
  ...`

See: http://jsbin.com/xequvone/14/edit

If you don't bind the `core-menu` directly to the `core-animated-pages`, you can add whatever logic you want. The following version does exactly the same thing as the previous one, but uses a separate variable for the selected page:

http://jsbin.com/xequvone/12/edit

I think you'd want a router if your URL scheme was more complex. For example, if the hash includes multiple levels and parameters, such as `#people`, `#/people/search` or `#/people/edit/12343`.

Answer (score 2):

Something I'm missing from reviewing your example is how you're handling routing. In a typical site, if a user navigates to `example.com/foo` or `example.com/#foo` my expectation would be (using your current setup) that that would take you to the corresponding `core-animated-pages` page with the ID `foo` or a section which corresponds to that route.

Using routing (maybe the Polymer [flatiron-director](https://github.com/PolymerLabs/flatiron-director) element), a basic solution might query the DOM in your element to see if a section of ID `notsupportedURL` can be found. If not, default to taking the user to your `core-animated-pages` 404 page, which doesn't have to be any more complex than what you have in place now.

Comment: I've added the way I link on my site currently. Initially removed that part of the code since I didn't think it was relevant. The problem is that now using data-binding the url is loaded directly into the `selected` field of the `core-animated-pages` and `core-menu`, so I don't really see how your solution would be implemented in practice.